# "Mid-autumn Festival" and "Moon Festival", Which is better known in English-speaking world?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today is the Mid-autumn Festival of China and I read an article of a Taiwanese scholar telling that his research finds Moon Festival is more better known to English speakers than Mid-autumn Festival, a coined phrase by Chinese, because some authoritative dicitionaries have  the entry of the former but not of the latter.

But I want to tell him that in our English textbook co-authored by Chinese and English native authors, we get only Mid-autumn Festival and never knows there is a name as "Moon Festival", perhaps it is a holiday of Indians living in Peru or Venezuela.

Answer (score 1):

Many, probably most, English speakers will have little or no awareness of this festival under either name, so when referring to it for a general English-language audience, it will be a good practice to include some explanation or description of the general nature or purpose of the festival, and where and when it is celebrated. A transliteration of the name of the festival in Chinese may be a good idea as well.

Answer (score 0):

While there are many autumnal festivals across the English-speaking world, each tends to have its own name and is known primarily in its own area.
For example:  [Somerset Carnivals](http://www.somersetcarnivals.co.uk/), [Tar Barrel Rolling](http://www.tarbarrels.co.uk/history/) or even the more widely known [Guy Fawkes Night](http://www.bonfirenight.net/).

Similar festivals in non-English speaking parts of the world would be referred to in English by the local name, or a translation of it.  Whether Moon Festival or Mid-Autumn Festival is better known is simply a matter of whether people know about them.